# React component return value changing without component rerendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a useRef() hook that I'm using in a parent component to keep track of if this is the user's first time on the landing page. This hook is passed to a child component, where it is used to decide which of two CSS classes to style a div with, after which the hook is updated so we know in the future that it's not their first time. These are the two components:

```js
function RootComponent() {
  const firstLanding = useRef(true);
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route exact path='/'>
          <Welcome firstLanding={firstLanding} />
        </Route>
        ... other routes
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
function Welcome(props) {
  var classUsed;

  if (props.firstLanding.current) {
    classUsed = "firstLandingClass";
    props.firstLanding.current = false;
  }
  else {
    classUsed = "normalClass";
  }
  
  console.log("Class used: " + classUsed);
  
  return (
    <div className={classUsed}>
      Content!
    </div>
  )
}
```

I was expecting this to work, but the first time visiting the site, it logs "Class used: firstLandingClass" and nothing else, while actually using normalClass (Confirmed by inspecting div in browser). Any ideas on why it's using the other class without logging a change to classUsed in the console or a better way to accomplish this task?

Any and all contributions are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

It's due to Strict Mode.

Mostly wrapped at Index.js

```
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
);
```

The class name becomes `normalClass` on the second component function call.

## Caveats

- Do not write or read ref.current during rendering, except for initialization. This makes your component’s behavior unpredictable.
- In Strict Mode, React will call your component function twice in order to help you find accidental impurities. This is development-only behavior and does not affect production.

## Solution

use useEffect and set the dependency array empty so that it'll run at once.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

const MyComponent = ({ isFirstRender }) => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFirstRender.current) {
      isFirstRender.current = false;
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      className={isFirstRender.current ? "First render" : "Not first render"}
    >
      <input
        type="text"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
      />
      <h1>First Render: {isFirstRender.current ? "Yes" : "No"}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const isFirstRender = useRef(true);

  return <MyComponent isFirstRender={isFirstRender} />;
}
```

If you want to play around with the [code](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/white-frog-6dx36k?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A10%2C10)

Comment: That worked, thank you! Though I'm curious why it didn't work initially... Oh well, question for another day.

Comment: @arkostin01 I'm glad I could help. I have added Issue and Caveats.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this, hope this will help you.

```
function Welcome(props) {
  console.log("props", props)
  const [classUsed, setClassUsed] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.firstLanding?.current ) {
      setClassUsed('firstLandingClass');
      props.firstLanding.current = false;
    }
    else {
      setClassUsed('normalClass');
    }
  },[]);

  console.log("Class used: " + classUsed);
  
  return (
    <div className={classUsed}>
      Content!
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I used Anshu's answer which also used useEffect(), so you were right!